Compare two files with same ids and substract fields
I have 2 files with the format of
File A
01  20200111  28.56  22.07  40.14  49.79  22.81  49.31  33.75  31.24  39.41  36.18
02  20200118  32.41  14.89  38.82  60.54  11.54  49.10  34.34  25.53  36.96  34.30
03  20200125  21.95  18.48  28.45  42.94  22.45  42.40  36.43  34.53  43.51  33.28
...
01  20210109  29.32  24.60  34.41  46.56  29.38  44.06  34.47  33.75  41.12  36.04
02  20210116  29.38  28.39  33.07  42.63  29.46  39.41  32.45  33.60  43.81  34.93
03  20210123  27.51  19.55  32.98  45.88  26.05  46.88  37.58  31.98  44.52  35.90



File B
01  19912020  24.20  16.70  31.28  45.98  19.26  42.57  33.43  29.35  39.96  32.22
02  19912020  24.29  15.46  29.02  44.47  19.24  40.57  32.98  29.80  40.26  31.36
03  19912020  20.69  14.07  29.90  45.89  21.34  44.71  35.90  31.61  42.00  33.08


I would like to take the difference of Columns 3-12 of each id (Column 1) in File A from the same unique id in File B. File A has multiple instances of the same id. So each instance would be compared to the same id in File B.
My desired output is:
01   20200111    4.36    5.37    8.86    3.81    3.55    6.74    0.32    1.89   -0.55    3.96
02   20200118    8.12   -0.57     9.8   16.07    -7.7    8.53    1.36   -4.27    -3.3    2.94
03   20200125    1.26    4.41   -1.45   -2.95    1.11   -2.31    0.53    2.92    1.51     0.2
...
01   20210109    5.12     7.9    3.13    0.58   10.12    1.49    1.04     4.4    1.16    3.82
02   20210116    5.09   12.93    4.05   -1.84   10.22   -1.16   -0.53     3.8    3.55    3.57
03   20210123    6.82    5.48    3.08   -0.01    4.71    2.17    1.68    0.37    2.52    2.82

The above output (cols 3-12) needs to be in the format of %8.2f
Any help is appreciated.

addressing the negative value issue .... the expected ouput seems to show that you wish to subtract File_B values from File_A values in which case you just need to flip the values, ie, change a[$1]-$3 to $3-a[$1]

what version of awk are you using? what is the output from awk --version?

please confirm that you want to change the value of the first column by stripping leading 0's

@markp-fuso Your first  comment works as expected. Thanks! But is there a way to easily print the difference of the remaining fields?
Also, I would like to preserve the leading 0's in the output.
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0-p9, GNU MP 6.2.0)

please update the question to show the desired output (eg, maintaining the leading 0); also, please indicate the input and output field spacing ... neither appears to be 'single space' nor 'single tab' ... or does the (output) spacing not matter?

@markp-fuso. Thank you for the help. I was able to get output as expected. The first column goes from 01 to 53. So never more than 2 digits. The output should be fixed width right justified, as you described. How would I adjust the printf statement?
printf "%s%0.2f" does not quite do it.

I asked a follow up question in my original post.

@markp-fuso I have rolled back the latest update and asked a new question based on my needs.

Sorry bout that. I have rolled everything back and posted a new question.

One idea using GNU awk (for multi-dimensional array support):
awk '
FNR==NR { for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)                    # 1st file: loop through 3rd-12th fields
              b[$1][i]=$i                        # store field values in 2-dimensional array
          next                                   # skip to next input line
        }
$1 in b { printf "%s  %s", $1, $2                # 2nd file: if $1 is index in first dimension of array b[] then printf first 2 fields and then ...
          for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)                    # loop through 3rd-12th fields
              printf "%8.2f", $i-b[$1][i]        # print the difference
          print ""                               # terminate the current line of output
        }
' File_B File_A                                  # process File_B first, then File_A

This generates:
01  20200111    4.36    5.37    8.86    3.81    3.55    6.74    0.32    1.89   -0.55    3.96
02  20200118    8.12   -0.57    9.80   16.07   -7.70    8.53    1.36   -4.27   -3.30    2.94
03  20200125    1.26    4.41   -1.45   -2.95    1.11   -2.31    0.53    2.92    1.51    0.20
01  20210109    5.12    7.90    3.13    0.58   10.12    1.49    1.04    4.40    1.16    3.82
02  20210116    5.09   12.93    4.05   -1.84   10.22   -1.16   -0.53    3.80    3.55    3.57
03  20210123    6.82    5.48    3.08   -0.01    4.71    2.17    1.68    0.37    2.52    2.82

NOTES:

output formatting may need to be tweaked based on OP's final requirement
if OP needs to maintain a variable number of decimal places (eg, 5.12 vs 7.9) then some additional coding could be added


UPDATE :: just realized 2 variables is all I need for the function :
01 20200111     4.36     5.37     8.86     3.81     3.55     6.74     0.32     1.89    -0.55     3.96
02 20200118     8.12    -0.57     9.80    16.07    -7.70     8.53     1.36    -4.27    -3.30     2.94
03 20200125     1.26     4.41    -1.45    -2.95     1.11    -2.31     0.53     2.92     1.51     0.20
...
01 20210109     5.12     7.90     3.13     0.58    10.12     1.49     1.04     4.40     1.16     3.82
02 20210116     5.09    12.93     4.05    -1.84    10.22    -1.16    -0.53     3.80     3.55     3.57
03 20210123     6.82     5.48     3.08    -0.01     4.71     2.17     1.68     0.37     2.52     2.82


    # gawk profile, created Fri Apr 26 11:18:42 2024

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
     1      CONVFMT = "%8.2f"
    }

    # Rule(s)

    10  {
    10      if (_ = NR == FNR)
     3          __[$_] = $!_
     7      else {
     7          if ($++_ in __)
     6              ___(__[$_])
     7          print
            }
        }


    # Functions, listed alphabetically

     6  function ___(_, __) {

     6      _ = split(_, __)

     6      delete __[_ ^= !_]
     6      delete __[++_]

    60      for (_ in __)
    60          $_ -= __[_]
         }


condensed down :
awk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%8.2f" } 

     function ___(_,__) {
         _ = split(_, __)
         delete __[_ ^= !_]
         delete __[++_]
         for (_ in __)
             $_ -= __[_] 
     } {
         if (_ = NR == FNR)
             __[$_] = $!_
         else {
             if ($++_ in __)
                 ___(__[$_])
             print 
         } 
     } '

########################
an approach for any awk variant - save the full row instead of by fields, and only split them out when needing to subtract
    # gawk profile, created Fri Apr 26 11:10:36 2024

    # Rule(s)

    10  {
    10      if (_ = NR == FNR)
     3          __[$_] = $!_
     7      else {
                if ($++_ in __)
                    ____(__[$_])
     7          print
            }
        }

    # Functions, listed alphabetically

     6  function ____(__, _, ___) {

     6       _ = split(__, ___)
     6      __ = "%8.2f"

     6      delete ___[_^=!_]
     6      delete ___[++_]

    60      for (_ in ___)
    60          $_ = sprintf(__, $_ - ___[_])
        }


01 20200111     4.36     5.37     8.86     3.81     3.55     6.74     0.32     1.89    -0.55     3.96
02 20200118     8.12    -0.57     9.80    16.07    -7.70     8.53     1.36    -4.27    -3.30     2.94
03 20200125     1.26     4.41    -1.45    -2.95     1.11    -2.31     0.53     2.92     1.51     0.20
...
01 20210109     5.12     7.90     3.13     0.58    10.12     1.49     1.04     4.40     1.16     3.82
02 20210116     5.09    12.93     4.05    -1.84    10.22    -1.16    -0.53     3.80     3.55     3.57
03 20210123     6.82     5.48     3.08    -0.01     4.71     2.17     1.68     0.37     2.52     2.82

